# Customize binaries folder in tfs 2013 - Adding configuration

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

How can I force TFS 2013 to drop files to different folders depending on the configuration built?

I want to get something like:

- `\\MyPath\Release\My Files`
- `\\MyPath\Debug\My Files`

In 2012 I used to add the `platformConfiguration.configuration` to the binaries folder to the MSBuild activity. That was possible because those activities were in a `for-each` activity so I was able to utilize the current build configuration from the `for-each`, but in TFS 2013 the default template does not wrap the MSBuild activity in a `for-each` activity so I don't know how to get the current configuration

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The for each is there it is just wrapped in a parent activity. If you configure your build, in the build configuration, to build one or more specific configurations it will work the same as the 2012 one.